# php sql query without foreach simple way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, statistics

I would like to make some statisctics. My database looks like that:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| id | value1     | value2     |  value 3   |     year     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | something1 | something3 | something5 |         2016 |
|  2 | something2 | something3 | something6 |         2015 |
|  3 | something1 | something4 | something5 |         2014 |
|  4 | something1 | something4 | something6 |         2016 |
|  5 | something2 | something3 | something5 |         2014 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

And my question is how to construct as simple as possible query or queries which counts values and returns an array which has structure below?

```
[0] =>
    ['year'] => 2014
    ['value1'] =>
        ['something1'] => 1
        ['something2'] => 1
    ['value2'] =>
        ['something3'] => 1
        ['something4'] => 1
    ['value3'] =>
        ['something5'] => 2
[1] =>
    ['year'] => 2015
    ['value1'] =>
        ['something2'] => 1
    ['value2'] =>
        ['something3'] => 1
    ['value3'] =>
        ['something6'] => 1
[2] =>
    ['year'] => 2016
    ['value1'] =>
        ['something1'] => 2
    ['value2'] =>
        ['something3'] => 1
        ['something4'] => 1
    ['value3'] =>
        ['something5'] => 1
        ['something6'] => 1
```

Comment: Hell, a loop would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a simple query:

```
(
 SELECT t2.`year`, 'value1' AS col, t2.value1 AS val_content, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM YourTable t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year`, t2.value1
) 
UNION 
(
 SELECT t2.`year`, 'value2' AS col, t2.value2 AS val_content, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM YourTable t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year` , t2.value2
)
UNION
(
 SELECT t2.`year`, 'value3' AS col, t2.value3 AS val_content, COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM YourTable t2
 GROUP BY t2.`year` , t2.value3
) 
ORDER BY 1 , 2 , 3;
```

I got this result:

```
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
| year | col    | val_content | total |
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
| 2014 | value1 | something1  |     1 |
| 2014 | value1 | something2  |     1 |
| 2014 | value2 | something3  |     1 |
| 2014 | value2 | something4  |     1 |
| 2014 | value3 | something5  |     2 |
| 2015 | value1 | something2  |     1 |
| 2015 | value2 | something3  |     1 |
| 2015 | value3 | something6  |     1 |
| 2016 | value1 | something1  |     2 |
| 2016 | value2 | something3  |     1 |
| 2016 | value2 | something4  |     1 |
| 2016 | value3 | something5  |     1 |
| 2016 | value3 | something6  |     1 |
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
```